# Why this is not terminating ```1 + (sizeofInt x `div` 10)```?

Tags: haskell

```
sizeofInt :: Int -> Int
sizeofInt 0 = 0
sizeofInt x = 1 + (sizeofInt x `div` 10)
```

Why does this function not terminate unless I put brackets around `` x `div` 10 ``?

**UPDATE**: fixed the case when number is 0

```
sizeofInt :: Int -> Int
sizeofInt x = if m == 0 then 1
  else 1 + sizeofInt m
  where m = x `div` 10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the brackets you're saying `` (sizeofInt x) `div` 10 ``, which calls `sizeofInt x` forever. Application always binds more tightly than any operator.

Comment: The expansion is fun.  `foo ~ 1 + foo \`div\` 10 ~  1 + (1 + foo \`div\` 10) \`div\` 10 ~ 1 + (1 + (1 + foo \`div\` 10) \`div\` 10) \`div\` 10 ~ ...`

Comment: I just realized that I made mistake for the case when x is 0. How would you account if it's a single number 0 to be of size 1?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Did you use Trace or something else to print that?